# How to add description to @requestbody?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

As shown in the picture, I want to add my description in my Swagger UI. The value "Example" (in name and description) comes from the parameter "Example" in the controller where I have used the @Requestbody. I am using Spring framework. How do I add my description to it?

[image]

This is my controller file

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "It will be used to print the document of quotation.",response = GenerateDocPrintResponse.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
                    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved list"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "You are not authorized to view the resource"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found")
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(value = "/service/generateDocPrint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String generateDocPrint(@RequestBody GetdocprintRequest Example,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            @RequestBody String newJson) throws Exception {
        ................
}
```

This is my Pojo file

```
package com.iii.fw.models.generatedocprint;
import com.iii.fw.models.common.RequestHeader;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

public class GetdocprintRequest {   
    RequestHeader reqHeader;
    private ReqPayloadGDP reqPayload;
    
    public ReqPayloadGDP getReqPayload() {
        return reqPayload;
    }

    public void setReqPayload(ReqPayloadGDP reqPayload) {
        this.reqPayload = reqPayload;
    }

    public GetdocprintRequest withReqPayload(ReqPayloadGDP reqPayload) {
        this.reqPayload = reqPayload;
        return this;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @ApiOperation(value = "It will be used to print the document of quotation. ",  notes = "put your description here ", response = )

Answer (score 0):

```
@ApiOperation(value = "It will be used to print the document of quotation. ", notes = "put your description here ", response = )
```

Does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the notes proptery.

> Using notes, we can provide more details about the operation. For instance, we can place a text describing the endpoint's restrictions:
>
> https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-apioperation-vs-apiresponse#2-the-notes-property

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Gets customer by ID", notes = "Customer must exist")
```